# Using Facebook's Graph API in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I went over the Facebook developer docs and generally around the internet but couldn't quite understand how to use the Facebook Graph API in iOS.
Specifically, I need to fetch a list of nearby locations using a given latitude&longitude. I came across this:
`GET /search?q={query}&type=place&center={lat},{lng}&distance={distance}`
But I don't understand where to even begin.
I have the Facebook SDK set up.

How do I call such request?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed by performing a simple URL request:

```
if let accessToken: FBSDKAccessToken? = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() {
    let urlString = "https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&center=\(geoPoint!.latitude),\(geoPoint!.longitude)&distance=1000&limit=10&access_token=\(accessToken!.tokenString)"
    let URL = NSURL(string: urlString)!

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if response != nil {
            let json = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers)
            print(json)
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to use the Facebook Graph request methods, some thing like this

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"fields" : @"", @"redirect" : @NO, @"type" : @"large"};
NSString *getPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/picture", @"fabebook_user_id"];
FBSDKGraphRequest *photoRequest = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:getPath parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
```

with this method i am getting the user photo, I think so this method can be useful for you too :)

Comment: Ok, looks good, do you have the equivalent to `GET /search?q={query}&type=place&center={lat},{lng}&distance={distance}` of your request so I can understand a little better how this works?